# Name for a set/collection of eggs which are laid and receive no nurturing of any sort by parents

Tags: terminology, reproduction

OK - so, mammals have **litters**, and they look after their young.

Hens (birds generally) have **clutches** and many/most look after their young.

Octopuses have **broods** since the female looks after the eggs, but expires
just as they hatch!

The thing I want to know is:

What is a group of eggs laid by a creature which just lays them and
moves on called?

Also of interest would be such creatures which lay single eggs periodically (is there a difference?).

I'm particularly interested in insects and the like, but any additional
words which may apply would be of interest, and yes, I have Googled but
to no avail!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bio.SE! This is a very broad question and likely has many thousands of correct answers. Perhaps you could help narrow things down by explaining why you want an answer to this question.

Comment: @James The reason I'm asking is because the info-graphic [here](https://aqua.org/-/media/Images/content/octopus_infographic.jpg) makes reference to the "average litter size" of the octopus. I told my lecturer (a comp. sci. person) that mammals had litters. I could only remember the word "clutch" for eggs, but didn't think that applied. After thinking, I came up with "brood" for octopuses. However, it led to me wondering about what one calls a set/collection of eggs that are just left by the female without any further nurturing. Octopus mothers brood till hatching, then die, but there is input!

Comment: Mammals generally nurse their young at least to some degree. I can think of no examples where mammalian young are left to fend for themselves immediately after birth. The names of groups of the young of animals is incredibly inconsistent, so I doubt this answer would have any roots in biology! It would be interesting if someone could prove me wrong.

Comment: @James - I've edited the question title. Mammals don't apply. [Some birds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maleo#Breeding_and_Habitat) may. Many insects lay the egg(s) and play no further role in nurturing the eggs/offspring! I want to know what is the set of eggs laid called - IMHO, it's **not** a litter, **nor* a clutch **nor** a brood!

Comment: Perhaps you'd have more luck over at the English language SE?